# android programming: Methods of Storing Forward(sending) user's location?

Tags: android, gps

I am a total novice on android programming and is relying on threads/solutions by veteran android programmers to enhance my application. For now I have 2 problems regarding our android app:

How and where could our users send their current location?
What ways can we store the location of our users and use it on our application?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a novice you should probably read the dev guide on [location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) and [storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).